# how to split ARG with string to seperated rows in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have dockerfile as

```
ARG VAR="something something2 something3 ... somethingN"
```

I want it as:

```
ARG VAR="something
         something2
         something3
         ....
         somethingN"
```

just changing it from 1 line statement to multiple lines

But I can't find the correct syntax to make it work. I know it's something with the `\` char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, continuation character `\` is the way, the whole syntax as next:

```
FROM alpine

ARG VAR="something \
something2 \
something3 \
... \
somethingN"

RUN echo $VAR
```

NOTE: don't add any `space` or `tab` after `\`.

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> 28f6e2705743
Step 2/3 : ARG VAR="something something2 something3 ... somethingN"
 ---> Running in 30ec9bed1131
Removing intermediate container 30ec9bed1131
 ---> e5d0cdb37272
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $VAR
 ---> Running in 1e6a05e5f218
something something2 something3 ... somethingN
Removing intermediate container 1e6a05e5f218
 ---> c8d3e865e34d
Successfully built c8d3e865e34d
Successfully tagged abc:1
```